# mysql - multiple foreign keys with different columns of different table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Would be great if someone provides me a hint to achieve this below scenario.

two foreign keys for table3

- FK1 referring to table1 column1
- FK2 referring to table 2 column1

Now when i insert a row to table 3 i want only FK1 to be active .

In other words right now mysql will not allow me insert a row until all foreign key constraints are satisfied. 
For me- my row should get inserted either if FK1 or FK2 is satisfied. Is there a way I can achieve this ?

Comment: Do each of these 2 foreign keys involve different columns?  Or do they both apply to the same column?

Comment: Also, maybe tell us why you think you need this requirement.  It is unusual to ask for a partial foreign key.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Same column

Comment: Same column referencing two different tables' columns? No, you really should never do that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen @Uueerdo Requirement is -  i have a two table EMP1 & EMP2 with emp1_reference_id and emp2_reference_id keys respectively. Now I need to have a new table `history` whose keys can be either value of emp1_reference_id or emp2_reference_id

Comment: @dishanm if there were an `emp1_reference_id` and an  `emp2_reference_id` with the same value, how would you know which one `history` referenced? _... and for MySQL to consider the FK constraints satisfied, you could only use such values anyway._

Comment: @Uueerdo we are sure emp1_reference_id and emp2_reference_id are always unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real simple way to have an either-or reference constraint; but you can make both FK constraints optional by making the referencing fields nullable.

This would not prevent a row from being inserted with both references null though. To prevent that possibility, you could use a BEFORE INSERT trigger to "throw an error" if an attempt to insert such a row was ever made. Then, you might want to consider a BEFORE UPDATE trigger to prevent rows from being changed in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

This is an atypical request, and might indicate that your design has a problem.  That being said, one idea which might work would be to create a new table containing just a single column.  This column is a primary key and will be populated via an after insert trigger on both table1 and table2.  The trigger will only insert if the value is not already in the table.  Now, in table3 you may put a foreign key constraint referencing this new column.  For the constraint to pass, there only need be one of the two tables having this primary key value.